# Programatically Create New ADF pipeline using Existing Pipeline with in same ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a new pipeline by doing a clone of existing pipeline. From portal, I can simply use clone option and do further modifications. By I need to automate the task of cloning the pipeline using Python. It will be really useful if someone give me pointer.

Steps I already did:

1. open Code section of my existing pipeline and copy JSON file. I am trying to programmatically alter JSON like pipeline name and variable value. When I send back the request, it give invalid dataset links. I followed MS documentation for this. Since in MS documentation, they are creating all from scratch, it may work but I am here interested to reuse the existing datasets and linked services.
2. I don't want to create ADF pipeline from scratch as I already have the reference pipeline which is bit complex.

Any suggestion would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing this out there as you did ask for "any suggestion".

You might be able to do this by setting up source control then programmatically duplicating/updating the relevant ARM templates. The key would be to work in the Collaboration branch and not the publish branch.